# i have a problem in my paint class

Tags: java

this is my code...

```
public class   Paintexample extends Applet{
    private Graphics g;
    JPanel panel;

    public void init()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.panel=new JPanel();
        this.panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024,500));
        this.add(panel);
        g=this.panel.getGraphics(); 
    }
    public void Painter(Graphics g2)
    {
        g2=this.panel.getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawRect(50, 50, 400, 400);
    }

}
```

the computer write this :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at Paintexample.Painter(Paintexample.java:27)
>         at Paintexample.init(Paintexample.java:22)
>         at Main.main(Main.java:15)

I don't know way the applet go's down....
the graphics does not works.....
he said the graphics are not init...

Comment: who is he who said the graphics are not init?

Comment: Are you calling Painter(...) before init()?

Comment: no i dident call to painter()

Comment: When you don't call it why you get an exception there?

Comment: This applet has many problems in its few lines. 1) Never call `getGraphics()` (see camickr's reply) 2) Don't mix layouts with custom painting. 3) An applet's size is set by the HTML, not by setting the preferred size of the main panel. 4) The `Graphics g` is declared and initialized without being further used. 5) The number of points already mentioned in other answers.  It seems you are **programming by putting random lines of code together in the vain hope they will work.**  That will get you nowhere fast.  Do the tutorials and understand the methods etc. that are being used.

Answer (score 3):

In one of your previous questions you were given a link to the Swing tutorial. I suggest you actually read the tutorial. It has sections on:

1. How to Make Applets - (you should be extending JApplet, not Applet)
2. Custom Painting - (this is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent), NOT by overriding paint() of the JApplet class

For further help you need to improve your "accept rate". 0% is too low!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want paint instead of Painter

```
public void paint(Graphics g2) {
    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.drawRect(50, 50, 400, 400);

}
```

Comment: i add into the init part this line at the end

Comment: after this line  g=this.panel.getGraphics();

Comment: @user650679 paint with a lowercase 'p' and don't call paint from `init()` it's called automatically when the applet need to be drawn or refreshed.

Comment: so where i need to call the paint()?

Comment: @user650679 you don't have to. it's automatically called when needed.

Comment: You shold NOT override the paint() method of a top level container.